# Prove there is such a triple

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

There are $3n$ colored numbers from $1$ to $3n$ such that each color is represented exactly by $n$ numbers. Prove there is 3-colored triple $a,b,c$ such as $$a+b=c$$

I started by assuming various values for minimum each of color, but didnt come to any conclusions(

Comment: How is the color assignment done? are there more constraints than the one you wrote?

Comment: No, just the restraint of each color being a color for exactly $n$ numbers

Comment: Then the question is pretty easy. Let $1$ be blue, $2$ be red, and $3$ be green. Then $1+2=3$, or am I missing something?

Comment: You dont do the coloring:) You are given a coloring with these conditions met, and you should prove that such triple exists

Comment: Already answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638163/prove-that-the-sum-of-two-elements-is-equal-third

Comment: @AkhmadSumekenov you should learn to deal with (and appreciate) the "you can prove it yourself, it is easy" parts of proofs, as long as the proof-writer is using that phrase appropriately

Comment: @mathworker21 unfortunately, sometimes i see such cases on this website. It is not often but it disappoints a lot

Comment: @AkhmadSumekenov what u just said was vague. in any event, nothing should be disappointing a lot

Comment: @RobPratt I wouldn't fully agree on your "already answered" statement. The other question (albeit similar) has an answer yielding a more general result. While the initial question can be solved *by itself*.

Comment: What does it means that "Prove there is 3-colored triple a,b,c"? all numbers are colored so one can find such triple. Do you meant $a$, $b$, $c$ are of different color?

Comment: @C.F.G:  yes, that means $a,b,c$ are all different colors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that this problem was initially asked and solved by Alekseev and Savchev, in the [Kvant journal, 4:23](http://kvant.mccme.ru/1987/04/p23.htm), problem M1040.

Let $A,B,C$ be the three monochromatic subsets of $[3n]$. Without loss of generality let $1,\ldots,k-1$ be in $A$ (i.e. the first $k-1$ integers are in $A$, with $k-1\geq1$), and let $k\in B$.

We call three numbers a good triple if they satisfy your condition. **Suppose that there are no good triple.**

Let $a\in C$ be any number. Note that $a-1\not\in B$ as otherwise $(1,a-1,a)$ would be a good triple.

**Suppose that $a-1\in C$**, and consider

1. The integer $a-k$. If it is in $A$ then $(a-k,k,a)$ would be a good triple. If it is in $B$, then $(k-1,a-k,a-1)$  would be a good triple. Therefore $a-k \in C$.
2. The integer $a-k-1$. If it is in $A$ then $(a-k-1,k,a-1)$ would be a good triple. If it is in $B$, then $(1,a-k-1,a-k)$  would be a good triple. Therefore $a-k-1 \in C$.
3. The integer $a-2k$. If it is in $A$ then $(a-2k,k,a-k)$ would be a good triple. If it is in $B$, then $(k-1,a-2k,a-k-1)$  would be a good triple. Therefore $a-k \in C$.
4. ...

Repeating this argument we conclude that all integers of the form $a-ik$ and $a-ik-1$ ($i=0,1,\ldots$) are in $C$. But note that because $a>k$, there exist some $i$ such that $ik\leq a \leq i(k+1)$ and therefore such that $1\leq a-ik \leq k$. And we know that this number is either in $B$ (if it is $k$) or in $A$ (if is it $<k$). Hence a contradiction, and $$a-1\in A$$

Therefore we proved that $\forall a\in C, \ a-1 \in A$. But note that $k-1\in A$ while $k\in B$ therefore there is at least one element $a\in A$ for which $a+1\not\in C$. Therefore $\vert A\vert > \vert C\vert$, a contradiction, and **there must be at least one good triple.**

Comment: I think the "Without loss of generality" part is the part that OP don't understand it.

Comment: I wouldn't know. OP never commented on the answer.